# child element clear parent's css

Tags: html, css

```css
#popBox{
  width:100%;
  height:100%; 
  position:fixed; 
  left:0;
  top:0; 
  border-collapse:collapse; 
  background:black;
  opacity:0.8; 
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<table id="popBox">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td id="popBox_container"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have a table set `opacity:0.8`.

Inside of this table, one of `td` opacity should be 1.

Is any way to clear set this td in different opacity?

Because there are 9 td in this table, I don't want to `<td class='opacity'>` set up a class and put in 8 elements.

Answer (score 2):

You can use pseudo selectors like `:nth-child()` or `:nth-of-type()` etc

Try like this

```
#popBox tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(1){
     opacity: 1;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/enN92/1/)

[image]

For more about these visit : [here](http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-class-selectors/)

Comment: +1 if the author doesn't bother about IE8 and earlier

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the logic behind this, but if you want for example to set the 5th td opacity 1 **without using additional classes and ids**, you can try to do it with jQuery like this:

```
$("td:eq(4)").css("opacity", "1");
```

Answer (score 1):

Opacity cannot be changed via inheritance.

Your best bet is to do this:

```css
#popBox td {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
#popBox #popBox_container {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<table id="popBox">
  <tr>
    <td>Something</td>
    <td>Something</td>
    <td>Something</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Something</td>
    <td id="popBox_container">Unique</td>
    <td>Something</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Something</td>
    <td>Something</td>
    <td>Something</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/enN92/)

Answer (score 1):

if you want for example that your `td#popBox_container` to have `opacity: 1` just add the style of this element after declaration of the style of your table :

```
<style>
#popBox{width:100%; height:100%; 
        position:fixed; left:0; top:0; 
        border-collapse:collapse; 
        background:black; opacity:0.8; 
        display:none;
}

#popBox #popBox_container{
   opacity: 1;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you apply `opacity` style to the parent, in this case `#popBox`, all children will inherit the style.

Answer (score 0):

The child will always inherit the opacity from its parent element. Opacity is not actually inherited in CSS. It's a post-rendering group transform.

You can use `background-color` with `rgba` instead of using opacity.

**HTML:**

```css
#popBox{
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
#popBox td{
  border:1px solid black;
}

#popBox td#popBox_container {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

```html
<table id="popBox">
 <tr>
    <td>Your Content</td>
    <td>Your Content</td>
    <td>Your Content</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Your Content</td>
    <td id="popBox_container">Your Content</td>
    <td>Your Content</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Your Content</td>
    <td>Your Content</td>
    <td>Your Content</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

[Try in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enN92/4/)

For getting a specific column, you can use pseudo selectors `:nth-child()`, `:first`, `:last` etc...

If we want to set opacity to first column into first table row - you can use this CSS Class:

```
#popBox tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1) {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    color:white;
}
```

[Try in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enN92/5/)